# Cypress file upload cy.Origin

Tags: file-upload, cypress, cypress-origin

When I use the cypress-file-upload plugin without the cy.origin() function, it works perfectly. However, when I introduce cy.origin() in my test, I get the error cy.get(...).attachFile is not a function, even though I've properly installed and imported the cypress-file-upload plugin in the commands.js file.

What I've tried:
Installed cypress-file-upload via npm.
Imported it in my cypress/support/commands.js file with import 'cypress-file-upload';.
Used the .attachFile() method without cy.origin() and it works perfectly.

Comment: You'll need to refer to docs to passing it to cy.origin() function.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Dependencies--Sharing-Code

Answer (score 1):

The origin command is still a bit new and evolving, but it does have an experimental switch that allows you to use `cypress-file-upload`.

First, in `cypress.config.js`, add the flag for `experimentalOriginDependencies`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

    },
    experimentalOriginDependencies: true, 
  },
})
```

Then follow the example for internal custom commands given here [cy.origin with Custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Custom-commands) since the cypress-file-upload lib is just another custom command.

#### A simple example

```js
cy.origin('https://example.com', () => {
  Cypress.require('../support/commands')
  assert(cy.attachFile, 'attachFile command is available')
})
```

This example passes

[image]

To see it fail without the `Cypress.require()`, comment it out

[image]

---

Since `cy.origin()` is just creating a new instance of the Cypress runner, I would expect eventually the `support/commands` and `support/e2e` files will be automatically add, and any library you use will be available inside cy.origin().